# Not able to get the Metric charts displayed using Hystrix dashboard in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, hystrix

I am trying to use Hystrix to implement service proxy to implement circuit breaker pattern. I did implement the Hystrix Commands and also package the Hystrix servlet to provide the Hystrix stream.  To monitor the services, I am using the Hystrix Dashboard 1.5.0.  All works fine on a local Tomcat server.  I am able to see the metrics charts

However, when I deploy the same on Bluemix, the Dashboard does not show the charts. Instead it says 'Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream.'.  I also checked the stream using Chrome browser. I am able to see the messages as below:

```
ping: 

data: 
{
    "type":"HystrixCommand",
    "name":"GetAllContactsCommand",
    "group":"GetAllContactsService",
    "currentTime":1464714539673,
    "isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,
    "errorPercentage":0,
    "errorCount":0,
    "requestCount":0,
    "rollingCountBadRequests":0,
    "rollingCountCollapsedRequests":0,
    "rollingCountEmit":0,
    "rollingCountExceptionsThrown":0,
    "rollingCountFailure":0,
    "rollingCountEmit":0,
    "rollingCountFallbackFailure":0,
    "rollingCountFallbackRejection":0,
    "rollingCountFallbackSuccess":0,
    "rollingCountResponsesFromCache":0,
    "rollingCountSemaphoreRejected":0,
    "rollingCountShortCircuited":0,
    "rollingCountSuccess":0,
    "rollingCountThreadPoolRejected":0,
    "rollingCountTimeout":0,
    "currentConcurrentExecutionCount":0,
    "rollingMaxConcurrentExecutionCount":0,
    "latencyExecute_mean":0,
    "latencyExecute":{"0":0,
    "25":0,
    "50":0,
    "75":0,
    "90":0,
    "95":0,
    "99":0,
    "99.5":0,
    "100":0
},
"latencyTotal_mean":0,
"latencyTotal":
{   "0":0,
    "25":0,
    "50":0,
    "75":0,
    "90":0,
    "95":0,
    "99":0,
    "99.5":0,
"100":0
},
"propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold":20,
"propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds":5000,
"propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage":50,
"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen":false,
"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed":false,
"propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled":true,
"propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy":"THREAD",
"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,
"propertyValue_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds":1000,
"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout":true,
"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride":null,
"propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,
"propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,
"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,
"propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled":true,
"propertyValue_requestLogEnabled":true,
"reportingHosts":1
}

data: 
{
    "type":"HystrixThreadPool",
    "name":"GetAllContactsService",
    "currentTime":1464714539673,
    "currentActiveCount":0,
    "currentCompletedTaskCount":3,
    "currentCorePoolSize":10,
    "currentLargestPoolSize":3,
    "currentMaximumPoolSize":10,
    "currentPoolSize":3,
    "currentQueueSize":0,
    "currentTaskCount":3,
    "rollingCountThreadsExecuted":0,
    "rollingMaxActiveThreads":0,
    "rollingCountCommandRejections":0,
    "propertyValue_queueSizeRejectionThreshold":5,
    "propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,
    "reportingHosts":1
}
```

Any idea, why the Dashboard is not able to connect to stream when deployed on Bluemix.  Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Umasuthan.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem trying to run on Bluemix.  I also run fine locally using Spring Tools Suite.  Has there been a resolution to this problem?

My situation:
I used the Spring Initialzr to create a Spring Cloud application (Eureka, Hystrix, REST controller).  I have deployed this to Bluemix (Cloud Foundry). Everything works fine except the Hystrix dashboard.  I get "Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream." on the dashboard.

I can curl the stream url - it takes a really long time but data does come back.